# Trigger python, Php, ruby or Javascript by mysql database change

Tags: mysql, windows-server

How can I make sure that specific changes in the database trigger a script?
I use windows server and mysql, and I can use the woocommerce api.

Comment: What kind of script? A database script, a windows script...? The database can have "triggers" that execute stored procedures but it sounds more like you want something to happen outside the database, in which case, you probably just need to query the database occasionally and act on the changes you find.

Comment: Its about running a file, that works as an api to woocommerce. So running cmd with -> python (path) argument1 argument2 would do the job. Best case would be an immediate run after the change was made.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really within relational database architecture for the database to be letting other programs know what's happening in the database. MySQL triggers can make changes *in* the database - for example, update one table each time there's an insert in another table. But they don't call external programs.

I think you basically have two options here.

1. Whatever is making changes to your data, have that thing also trigger the script you want to trigger.
2. Have your script query the database every 5 minutes (or even every 1 minute) and act on changes. You can find changes by creating a column that tells you when a row was last updated, and having your script use the timestamp; or creating a column that marks rows when they've been acted on by your script (slightly more reliable).